# Is there a way to click a window's default button in Applescript without knowing its name or number?

Tags: applescript

I have seen dialog where the default button is the Cancel button and Accessibility Inspector says that button is still button 2, **NOT** button 1.

So I'm asking if there's a way to click the default button **without** knowing its name or number as it may not be button 1 in some very rare cases?

I've already tried `click default button`, which generated a syntax error and `click button default` which generated an error saying "default" was an undefined variable.

Comment: the default button is "clicked" by using enter key. Make the relevant application upfront and simulate enter key via keystroke command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the default button, you just need to press the "Return" key ⏎

```
tell application "This App" to activate -- to bring it to the front if necessary

tell application "System Events" to key code 36 -- simulates pressing the return key
```

Comment: Just found out you can also say `keystroke return` instead of `key code 36`.